# Isto é incomum ou é um bug?

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, perguntas

Estava vendo algumas questões que receberam atividades recentes e uma me chamou muita atenção pelo fato de haver muitas visualizações:

> [Erro no v7 appcompat nos themes v21](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37437/erro-no-v7-appcompat-nos-themes-v21)

Ela obteve 1118 (até agora) visualizações em 11 dias, o que está mais de 1000% acima da média de visualizações (comparado com as [perguntas do mês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=month) de Outubro). Até então eu analisei mais profundamente o conteúdo e as respostas recebidas, e todas as respostas e a pergunta não possuem nenhum ponto positivo ou negativo*.

Isto pode ser um bug ou é apenas uma situação incomum?

<sub>* *Infelizmente não possuo pontos suficientes para visualizar votos positivos e negativos. Pessoalmente, não sei se o problema da questão é tão procurado assim...*</sub>

Comment: Está 0-0 os pontos positivos-negativos

Comment: Obrigado @JorgeB.!

Comment: Utilidade útil: [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/10590)

Comment: É possível que algum termo contido na resposta tenha sido indexado pelo Google atraindo muitos visitantes que não possuem conta no site. Isso justificaria o alto número de visualização e nenhum voto, entretanto é mais um chute.

Comment: é comum acredito. Eu tive e resolvi sozinho, não sei explicar, não é uma coisa relacionada a programação nem uma duvida frequente, acho que por isso n teve muitos pontos. 
Acontece o bug e a pessoa faz uma "Limpeza" e volta. 
eu por exemplo troquei o workspace

Comment: @brasofilo, muito bom essa extensão do Chrome! Mas parece não funcionar no SOpt :(

Comment: @Math! Talvez tenha razão! Procurei pelos termos: *"v7 appcompat error"*, *"error themes v21"*, *"erro appcompat"* e em todos eles a página indexada da pergunta apareceu entre os 5 primeiros. Talvez tenha sido isto mesmo!

Comment: @biio, fiz um bug report e o autor já consertou o problema, é só atualizar o script.